# mkl_intel_thread.dll error while installing flopy package

Tags: python, anaconda

This is my first time to install a python package.

I want to install [**flopy package**](https://pypi.org/project/flopy/) 
The path to anaconda3 at my PC is

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
```

Following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4H7Lh9cpGE), I typed in anaconda prompt

```
cd "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3"
python -m pip install flopy
```

I got the following

```
Collecting flopy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/f3/7d86d8d83e6d71a05557796d303604c24c9896743be861433471d576bbb7/flopy-3.2.12.zip
```

and this error window appeared

```
The ordinal 242 could not be located in the dynamic link library
c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_intel_thread.dll.
```

In anconda prompt

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 2:
     command: 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-p3cq3l3y\\flopy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-p3cq3l3y\\flopy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p3cq3l3y\flopy\
    Complete output (2 lines):
    INTEL MKL ERROR: The operating system cannot run %1. mkl_intel_thread.dll.
    Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 2: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

mkl_intel_thread_dll is in this path

```
where  mkl_intel_thread.dll
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_intel_thread.dll
```

Any suggestions to fix this error will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That video is old and just bad advice in terms of Conda best practice. FloPy is available on the Conda Forge channel in Anaconda Cloud, which can be installed with

```
conda install -c conda-forge flopy
```